# Unable to decrease width/height of div in quirks mode for IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, dojo, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

This is a weird issue that I am facing

In short I am unable to decrease width/height of a div in quirks mode for IE9

Longer description I am using a customized (by myself) dijit.Dialog with dojox.resizeHandle widget.

When it shows for the first time, I can resize it without any problem. However once hidden, on being shown it is not possible to decrease its size, only increase it.

On debugging I found that while sizes were correctly applied in Trace Style, however it wasn't rendering in Layout.

Comment: There will be a lot of weirdnesses when using almost fourteen years old browser. [IE5.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_5#History) was released in July 2000....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution, this "weird" behavior is caused because in "quirks" mode "div" which doesn't have "hasLayout" is not able to shrink

Fix is to force "div" element to have "hasLayout" set to true

I did it by setting "zoom" to "1"

```
dojo.style(this.containerNode,"zoom","1");
```

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481.aspx